# jsoup 400 error on correct url

Tags: http, http-headers, jsoup

I am using mozilla rest client and sending a post request on a URL, Its Spring controller, I get 200 status on Mozilla plugin, Where as the same url does not work in jsoup any help is appreciated below is error.

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400, URL=http://localhost:8080/SelfServices/service/mulOrderStatus
```

jsoup:

```
Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:8080/SelfServices/service/mulOrderStatus")
                    .header("Content-Type", "text/html")
                    .timeout(5000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .post();
```

Comment: Is this a post request without parameters? Could that be the problem maybe?

Comment: Can you add relevant sections of your request using the Mozzila plugin?